# What is a good book for learning Stochastic Calculus?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, book-recommendation

I am in search of a good book for learning Stochastic Calculus from a purely mathematical/statistical point of view. Almost all the books I see are based on Finance. Also, please specify the pre-requisites for this course.

Actually, I am quite knowledgable in Measure Theory, Markov Chains and Martingale Theory. I believe this knowledge should suffice.

I am planning to self-study this subject. Please suggest me good books.

Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-calculus+book-recommendation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've been told, [Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus by Karatzas and Shreve](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0949-2) is the gold standard.

[Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion by Revuz and Yor](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAAahUKEwjAqNrRtszHAhUO74AKHb6NA5w&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fus%2Fbook%2F9783540643258&ei=EKvgVcDgBo7egwS-m47gCQ&usg=AFQjCNGebGlU_sPrMnyDNM4DkdU6fCfWBQ&sig2=h3z_4i8nJicRZqKC_kWckw) is also a great reference. What you have listed as background knowledge is sufficient.